# Directly 'save as' an embedded image with Vimperator using hint-mode

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, vimperator

How do I directly *'save as'* an embedded image `<img>` chosen with hint-mode in [Vimperator](http://vimperator.org/trac/wiki/Vimperator)?
Hit a keystroke, choose which image with a number ([hint](http://vimperator.sourceforge.net/help/vimperator/hints.xhtml)), and the *'save as'*-window will pop up.

You could use the context menu with `;c` and choose the *'save as'*-option. Alternatively open the image in a new tab with `;I` and save it with `ctrl+s`, but it's slow when wanting to save a lot of images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a somewhat "hidden" feature in Vimperator:
**`;S` - save a media object**

For some reason it's not listed in the online version of Vimperator's Hint documentation, only on the one included in the addon (using `:h`). It's also quite hard to search for this unless you use *"media"* instead of *"image*" in your search query.
Hopefully this Q&A will help with that.